# Python returns error "Arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type"

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am try to fitting with myself 2d Gaussian. Main goal is extract the parameters of Gaussian. Here my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit,fmin

def Gauss2(x,y, amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta, bgr):
      xo = float(xo)
      yo = float(yo)    
      a = (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
      b = -(np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_y**2)
      c = (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
      g = bgr + amplitude*np.exp( - (a*((x-xo)**2) + 2*b*(x-xo)*(y-yo) 
                        + c*((y-yo)**2)))
      return g

xsz = 40
ysz = 40

x0=xsz/2
y0=ysz/2

MInt1=200
bgr=10
noise=5

sigma_x = 5.
sigma_y = 4.

### create random Gaussian 2d
x = np.linspace(0, xsz-1, xsz)
y = np.linspace(0, xsz-1, xsz)
xx1, yy1 = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ex1=np.exp(-(((xx1-x0)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + ((yy1-y0)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)))
z1 = MInt1* random.uniform(0, 1)*noise* ex1

theta=0
#aa=Gauss2(xx1,yy1, MInt1,x0,y0,sigma_x,sigma_y,theta,bgr)

poptX, pcovX = curve_fit(Gauss2, z1[x,y], p0=[x,y, MInt1,x0,y0,sigma_x,sigma_y,theta,bgr])

img = z1.reshape((xsz,xsz))
plt.imshow(img); plt.colorbar();plt.show()
```

I getting this message:

> IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Comment: please post the full error traceback!

Comment: error in which line ?

Comment: I suspect the `z1[x,y]` expression. `x` and `y` are produced by `linspace`, and thus floats (even if they could be rounded to integers).  There aren't many indexing operations.

Comment: @Raju: thanks for wanting to edit questions here. I approved your edit, but please don't use all-caps - it is widely understood as shouting.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = np.linspace(0, xsz-1, xsz, dtype='int')
y = np.linspace(0, xsz-1, xsz, dtype='int')
```

so that

```
z1[x, y]
```

will work (provided `z1` is the right size)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues you'll run into. First:

```
x = np.linspace(0, xsz-1, xsz, dtype=np.int)
y = np.linspace(0, xsz-1, xsz, dtype=np.int)
```

Will cast `x` and `y` to be integer types so that you can index into `z1` and get rid of the error you're currently seeing.

Also, your call to `curve_fit` will have a few issues. The call should look something like:

```
poptX, pcovX = curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=[p1, ..., pn])
```

If I'm interpreting what you're trying to accomplish, which seems to be fitting a 1-dimensional curve within a 2D gaussian, you'll have to do something like the following:

```
 poptX, pcovX = curve_fit(Gauss2, (x, y), z1[x, y], p0=[MInt1,x0,y0,sigma_x,sigma_y,theta,bgr])
```

Which requires you doing just a very slight modification to your definition of `Gauss2`, since scipy expects data to be passed in as the first positional argument:

```
def Gauss2(X, amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta, bgr):
      x, y = X # Pack x, y params into X
      xo = float(xo)
      yo = float(yo)    
      a = (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
      b = -(np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_y**2)
      c = (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
      g = bgr + amplitude*np.exp( - (a*((x-xo)**2) + 2*b*(x-xo)*(y-yo) 
                        + c*((y-yo)**2)))
      return g
```

Comment: Hi all,
Thanks a lot for discuss.
The problem "IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type"  is solved.

Comment: @OtabekBur my answer likely explains the issue you're seeing with `curve_fit` as well.